# selected file upload not working in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm trying to upload file in Angular7 Application, but getting response status 400 error.

Same API worked for file upload in Angularjs, it's working fine.

AngularJS Code:

```
            url: serviceUrl + '/docs/UploadFiles',
            headers: {
                Authorization: $scope.userData.token
            },
            data: {
                file: capturedImagefile,
                name: capturedImagefile.localURL,
                refno: $scope.ticketLogData,
                createby: $scope.userData.username,
                dtype: 'Ticket-File',
                companyid: $scope.userData.companyid
            },

        });
```

Angular7 Code:

```
uploadPic(files: File) {
   this.imageDetails = files[0];
   console.log(this.imageDetails);
   const data = {
     file: this.imageDetails,
     name: this.imageDetails.name,
     refno: 123456,
     createby: 'nayank',
     dtype: 'Ticket-File',
     companyid: 1010
   };
this.httpclient.post(url, data) .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "url", ok: false, …}

Comment: Send your data as FormData instead of JSON. var data = new FormData(); data.append('file', this.imageDetails) ...

Comment: I tried that way as well but same error getting in response.

Comment: Showing error while appending into FormData - Getting TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode